# Communication site access to my files

Tags: sharepoint-online, communication-site

I have created a communication site and given read-only access to some email addresses. However, I noticed that some documents appear in "my files" on the left side menu that I do not want them to view. I suspect that those documents were shared by management via email in the past.

In the communication site, I have uploaded only a few documents that I want to share with the group. Is there a way I can hide "my files" or I would go delete them from the folders?

Thanks

Comment: Those files are visible to only you or other users as well? The documents shown in "My FIles" section of [SharePoint App Bar](https://ganeshsanapblogs.wordpress.com/2021/02/24/introducing-a-sharepoint-app-bar-that-features-global-navigation/) are specific to your user account only (those will be from all sites, not only the current communication site) and every user will see different files in that section. Let me know if it answers your question.